# How to fix sudden charge drop in stand by?

Tags: settings, battery-life, 5.1-lollipop

[image]

I have an android device running Lollipop 5.1 (the brand is local in my country) which has a battery draining problem in stand by mode.

- It drains about 10% of battery every hour or so without having any custom launcher
- The battery capacity is 1850 mAh
- WiFi is turned off. I only use one SIM
- I have been monitoring the phone since I bought it, I haven't used it to call someone and my network signal is completely stable and the only time spent on screen is to check battery percentage.

**Should I be worried or is it okay for such a device to consume this much battery in stand by mode?**

**Note:** I tried installing launchers which seem to be causing more battery consumption in stand-by.  I uninstalled all third party battery saver apps and turned android integrated power saver on.I also tried factory resetting the phone twice.

Comment: Did you check Battery section under Settings? See what apps are consuming so much battery.

Comment: I've uploaded a picture.See if it helps you to get the idea...I can't customize as it drains more battery in stand by

Comment: You can try checking if the behaviour repeats in safe mode. If it does, more likely it is battery issue. If not, it could be driver corruption issue and re-flashing ROM could fix

Comment: @beshyams I have a few days of replacement warranty left and don't know if reflashing would void it.....I forgot to mention that the phone has an integrated launcher....but it's very similar to stock android.

Comment: In which case replacing the battery would eliminate one problem (worst case) or solve the problem (best case). Suggest you get replacement done within warranty period. Current behaviour **is definitely NOT normal**

Comment: @beeshyams (Sorry to bother you again) I took my phone to the official outlet they kept it for nearly 17 hours.They said that they had re-flashed the ROM and used it.It was working fine and there was battery usage data.When I got home I did a factory reset and same problems showed up again. Used wifi for about an hour and yet it still shows "battery usage data isn't available".....So,would re-flashing it again be a good idea?

Comment: After they returned your phone, did you install any apps? Why did you need to reset? Not clear on that. If you installed apps and they messed up battery history-this is something possible if it is rogue app and you need to check all apps. Best is to reflash and keep it under observation longer without installing any apps. If you didn't install Any apps , return device and insist on replacement

Comment: @beeshyams  the phone was lagging a little bit and they had used it so I did a factory reset just to clear up data and accounts.After the reset I updated some apps like facebook,youtube,viber which were pre-installed.

Comment: Suggest inform the dealer about this and insist on replacement

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your battery is trash. Sometimes you buy a new phone and get a bad battery.

Take it back where you bought it and tell them the battery is bad. They should give you a new battery free of charge.